# Footnote inside Footnote does not appear (with Manyfoot)

Tags: luatex, footnotes, koma-script

I am using `manyfoot` package with `KOMA` and I really need to use footnote inside footnote. Everything compiles fine, but my new level of footnotes does not appear!

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[para*, perpage]{manyfoot}
%\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[roman]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}} Aenean non neque commodo lectus porta laoreet.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Donec eget vestibulum erat, ut semper felis. Sed faucibus, nisi vitae tincidunt mollis, augue nulla laoreet nibh, vel auctor mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  risus consequat tellus. Vestibulum\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  sed felis vestibulum eros faucibus lacinia quis ac\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  lorem. Pellentesque pulvinar\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  rutrum risus quis accumsan. Nullam interdum hendrerit\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  erat vel porttitor.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Suspendisse venenatis laoreet venenatis. Quisque luctus erat at lorem malesuada,\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec dapibus est tincidunt. Fusce a arcu nibh. Donec pretium massa sit amet\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  ultricies rhoncus.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nulla vestibulum lacinia nisl, bibendum tincidunt neque viverra non. Mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  viverra tellus et metus convallis suscipit id in nisi. Mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec libero ac\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  leo pharetra varius. Vestibulum suscipit, enim sed\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  molestie consectetur, libero\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  metus\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  finibus nulla,\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  pellentesque semper sapien orci id tortor. Morbi dignissim sem velit\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}} , non convallis odio\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  tincidunt vitae.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nullam vitae\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  justo posuere, sagittis purus eu, blandit tellus.
\end{document}
```

My Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that manyfoot supports nesting. With bigfoot it works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[roman]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}} Aenean non neque commodo lectus porta 
laoreet.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Donec eget vestibulum 
erat, ut semper felis. Sed faucibus, nisi vitae tincidunt mollis, augue nulla 
laoreet nibh, vel auctor mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  
risus consequat tellus. Vestibulum\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  sed felis vestibulum eros faucibus lacinia 
quis ac\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  lorem. Pellentesque 
pulvinar\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  rutrum risus quis 
accumsan. Nullam interdum hendrerit\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  erat vel porttitor.\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Suspendisse venenatis laoreet venenatis. 
Quisque luctus erat at lorem malesuada,\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec dapibus est tincidunt. Fusce a arcu nibh. 
Donec pretium massa sit amet\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  
ultricies rhoncus.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nulla 
vestibulum lacinia nisl, bibendum tincidunt neque viverra non. 
Mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  viverra tellus et metus 
convallis suscipit id in nisi. Mauris\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec libero ac\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  leo pharetra varius. Vestibulum suscipit, enim 
sed\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  molestie consectetur, 
libero\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  metus\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  finibus nulla,\footnote{here a 
footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  pellentesque semper sapien orci id tortor. 
Morbi dignissim sem velit\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}} , non 
convallis odio\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  tincidunt 
vitae.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nullam 
vitae\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  justo posuere, sagittis 
purus eu, blandit tellus. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use footnotes in your books, Don. \author JILL ^{KNUTH} (1962)

Comment: I tried `bigfoot` without the command `\DeclareNewFootnote{default}`and I got the error `\footinsA  forbidden in \footinsdefault` What is this command doing? Also, I have a problem with the footnote styles, but I will create another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\footnotemarkA` inside a footnote, but not `\footnotetextA`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[para*, perpage]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[roman]

\begin{document}
Token sentence\footnote{here a footnote\footnotemarkA}\footnotetextA{where??}.
Token sentence\footnote{here a footnote\footnotemarkA}\footnotetextA{where??}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But splitting the command is impracticable for me :(