# Why produces `\clearpage\chapter ...` the error `Float(s) lost. \clearpage` - How to finish a chapter and flush floats?

Tags: chapters, clearpage

I have read [this explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage) and some other hints about `Floats lost`. I use `tufte-book` and have more margin notes than fit on the page. The same text prints fine when processed separately but I combine it with others as chapters in a template and then the error occurs when the next chapter starts.

I assumed that \clearpage would process all pending floats and push them on a new page. In my case, the new chapter start seems to cause the loss suppressing the additional page needed.

How do I finish a chapter and have the pending margin notes on an additional page before the new chapter starts?

The snippet

```
\clearpage\part{xxx}
\begin{mdframed}\sloppy\medskip
some text\end{mdframed}
Some other more text...
```

seems not to do it.

I use `lualatex` to process and have `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (format=lualatex 2023.7.3)  13 JUL 2023 10:36 restricted system commands enabled.`

Producing a MWE showed that the problem is cause by two different issues when converting a `markdown` file with pandoc to `tex`

- the automatic production of citations as footnotes (using `\autocite`) producing footnotes inside footnotes
- footnotes inside footnotes confuse the footnote issuing sequence

resulting in a lost marginnote for each case of a footnote inside a footnote (at the end) and misplacement of the footnotes.

footnotes inside footnote are already   [mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508753/avoid-footnotes-inside-footnotes) and   an other issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665885/footnote-inside-footnote-does-not-appear-with-manyfoot). In my case produced by `autocite`, I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/biblatex-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes) which I have not yet tested.

Comment: You should provide a full but minimal example others can test. Then it is a lot easier to tell what you're doing wrong. Please make sure the example is self contained, fie example by using the images that comes with the mwe package.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. A few hours work to produce a MWE showed that there existed to issues which together produced the phenomenon. I edited the question, perhaps it is useful for others running in the same or a similar problem.